# Using Custom Font - Failed to decode downloaded font in Oracle Apex

Tags: html, css, font-face, custom-font

I'm trying to use some customized font in my application.

So i tried downloading [Pacifico](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/pacifico) and trying to use in my application. But getting `Failed to decode downloaded font` and the font is not loading

Below is my CSS .

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src:  url('#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#Pacifico.ttf')  format('ttf');
}

body {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

This is not working. So i tried converting this to `.woff` as per suggestions found in web and tried below. Even this is failing. I'm using Chrome `74.0` version . How to solve this?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#Pacifico.ttf')  format('ttf'), 
       url('#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#Pacifico.woff')  format('woff'),
       url('#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#Pacifico.woff2')  format('woff2');
}

body {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: hi, were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is you need upload the font into /i/

```
@font-face {
      font-family: "Pacifico";
      src: url("http://localhost:8080/i/Pacifico.ttf");
    }

body {
    font-family: "Pacifico", serif;
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    line-height: 25px !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
}
```

[image]

I don't know why Apex is not resolving the #WORKSPACE_IMAGES# but you can upload the font in the web server. In my case I'm using tomcat

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I don't have access to upload to /i/ folder. So i couldn't check